# Placing controls inside a panel in C#

Tags: c#

```
private void newThumbNail(int docType, string fileName)
        {

            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt] = new GroupBox();
            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Parent = panel1;            
            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;            
            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(2, 5);
            thmbNail[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(222, 50);



            picBox[thmbNailCnt] = new PictureBox();
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Parent = thmbNail[thmbNailCnt];
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(6, 13);
            picBox[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(31, 31);
            //picBox[thmbNailCnt].Image = new Bitmap("images/excel.png");

            texBox[thmbNailCnt] = new TextBox();
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Parent = thmbNail[thmbNailCnt];
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Visible = true;
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Location = new Point(53, 24);
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Size = new Size(163, 20);
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Text = fileName;
            texBox[thmbNailCnt].Enabled = false;

            Controls.Add(thmbNail[thmbNailCnt]);
            Controls.Add(picBox[thmbNailCnt]);
            Controls.Add(texBox[thmbNailCnt]);


        }
```

this is a function that dynamically adds a groupBox with some controls int it inside a panel. Unfortunately it does not appears inside the panel. The panel was created before hand using the c# design tools. It is placed directly on top of the windows form at 15,52 having a size of 279,489. Help please.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are adding these controls to the form controls collection.
Instead you should use the panel controls collection like:

```
    panel1.Controls.Add(thmbNail[thmbNailCnt]); 
    panel1.Controls.Add(picBox[thmbNailCnt]); 
    panel1.Controls.Add(texBox[thmbNailCnt]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Panel.Controls.Add(thmbNail[thmbNailCnt])

Also a tip to make your code faster and easier to read:

```
// Not modified to use Panel.Controls.Add()
GroupBox box = new GroouBox();
thmbNail[thmbNailCnt] = box;
box.Parent = panel1;            
box.Visible = true;            
box.Location = new Point(2, 5);
box.Size = new Size(222, 50);
```